# Can't grab string from URL with special characters

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a database in UTF8 unicode ci collation that stores values with special chars like:

```
oukaïmeden
```

I want to be able to form urls like:

```
example.com/oukaïmeden
```

or

```
example.com/index.php?id=oukaïmeden
```

In index.php I set the HTML charset as UTF8 (not that it matters pre output), and save the PHP file as UTF8 unicode ci.

However, no matter what I do, I cannot see to get the string in the form oukaïmeden so I can use it to search the database.

```
$aparams = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
extract($_GET);
$id = utf8_decode($aparams[1]);
echo $id;
echo urldecode($id);
echo utf8_decode($id);
echo utf8_encode($id);
```

I get values like:

```
ouka%C3%AFmeden
oukaÃ¯meden
```

I thought my question was "how can I get the string to show the umlaut so I can use it to search/compare etc?" But actually I wonder if I should be searching differently as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs cannot contain non-ASCII characters. The URL ***must*** look like this first and foremost to be correct:

```
example.com/index.php?id=ouka%C3%AFmeden
```

That's the correct [percent-encoded](http://php.net/rawurlencode) representation of the UTF-8 encoded word "oukaïmeden". The browser may or may not show this as "oukaïmeden" in your address bar, but the actual URL must be as above.

In PHP, reading this from `$_GET` will give you the already decoded value. So, to get the UTF-8 encoded string in your PHP script:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Yup, that's it. Nothing more needed.

Comment: Thanks, and that makes sense but then I am still querying my database with "ouka%C3%AFmeden" instead of "oukaïmeden" which returns no results. Should I be storing my data in a different way (percent encoded) or modifying the percent encoded value to query?

Comment: Again: taking the value from `$_GET`, **it's already decoded**. `$_GET['id']` is "oukaïmeden" (UTF-8 encoded), not "ouka%C3%AFmeden".

Comment: But that is not what I am seeing in my test and I'm not using GET. Does it make a difference that I am using mod-rewrite with htaccess and using explode on the REQUEST_URI $_SERVER global?

Comment: If I just look at $_GET['id'], via extract(), I get "oukaÃ¯meden".

Comment: The data in `$_SERVER` is ***not automatically decoded***. What you're seeing with `$_GET` is because your browser is not interpreting the result as UTF-8. The data is fine.

Comment: This is **before** I pass it to the browser. If I use `utf8_decode` on the variable directly from GET, and query the database, it works. If I pass it clean, it doesn't. It's not making sense (to me).

Comment: If `utf8_decode` makes it work, that means you expect Latin-1 encoded data. Make sure you use UTF-8 everywhere. http://kunststube.net/frontback

Answer (score -2):

Here is the output using the so the correct to use is the "utf8_encode"

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = utf8_decode($id);
echo $id."<br />";
echo urldecode($id)."<br />";
echo utf8_decode($id)."<br />";
echo utf8_encode($id)."<br />";  

ouka�meden
ouka�meden
ouka?meden
oukaïmeden
```

Comment: did you try to put this on your <head> tag 
"<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />"

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this in the original post.